# Warning: Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: nivo-slider

I am using nivo line component to draw a stacked line graph.  I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `L1.87.83999837239584`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version
```

What keys and children is it talking about?  Is it remotely possible that each data point on the graph is a distinct React element which is part of some collection and must be uniquely identified in "react sense"?

Answer (score 4):

so apparently Nivo takes your x,y data pairs and combines each pair values into react key used for identity within a collection.  Which means if you have a duplicate x,y pair, you end up with a duplicate key which causes the error I had reported.
It also blows up on having 2 same x values and different y values -- doesnt know how to handle that.

Comment: I believe I have simply filtered for duplicate x,y pairs and did not add duplicates to my collection.  So in other words, NO, there is no work around when working with the package -- I had to make sure my data does not violate Nivo limitations